# Delphi Prism Application Settings

Tags: wpf, delphi-prism, oxygene

In .net you can acces the Properties of your application trough code. How can you do the same in Oxygene / delphi prism ?

```
Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, to access the settings of your application, you must add the 
`YourAppNameSpace.Properties` namespace to your uses clause and then access the setting on this way

```
Settings.Default.MySettingName
```

Or using a full qualified name, like so :

```
YourAppNameSpace.Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName
```